# Passing selected checkbox from array data into database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm newbie for codeigniter. i trying to passing data attendance into database.

this my view code

```
<?php $no=1; foreach($employee AS $list_emp) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $no ?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="employee[]" value="<?php echo $list_emp->sn; ?>"><?= $list_emp->name; ?></td>
    <td><?= $list_emp->position; ?></td>
    <?php foreach ($attend_detail AS $list) {?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="detail[]" value="<?php echo $list['details']"></td>
    <?php } ?>
    <td><input type="text" name="note[]"></td>                      
    <input type="hidden" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $list_emp->branch; ?>">
    </tr>
<?php $no++;} ?>
```

[image: my view]

when i checked for 1 employee attendance (example 4630 is work), data can pass to database, but result like this (see image 2)

[image: image 2]

all data view input to database, not data when 1 checked before and remark WORK insert into row 1.

this my controller

```
function add_attend()
{
    $employee   = $this->input->post('employee');
    $location   = $this->input->post('location');
    $detail     = $this->input->post('detail');
    $note       = $this->input->post('note');
    $total      = count($employee);
    if (empty($detail) === true) { $errors['detail'] = 'please select one';}

    if (!empty($errors)){
        $info['success'] = false;
        $info['errors']  = $errors;
    }

    else {
        for ($x=0; $x<$total; $x++){
        $data = array(
            'sn'    => $employee[$x],
            'lab'   => $location[$x],
            'stat'  => $detail[$x],
            'note'  => $note[$x]
            );          
        $this->m_human_capital->insert_attend($data);
        }

        $info['success'] = true;
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($info));
}
```

and this my model

```
function insert_attend($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('tb_attend_tes',$data);
}
```

i just want insert employee attendance who i checked. please help

thanks for anyone help.

sorry my bad english

Comment: where is your `note` field  ? because if its in the same line as your attendance list - your db structure doesnt make any sense ... you need a m:n relation for your attendances but only a 1:1 relation for your note - or should note be duplicated for each attendance ?

Comment: sorry for missing part picture, NOTE field at the right of the picture, and it's no problem if empty. i have tried with fill the NOTE and the problem still same.

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: @MardinoIsmail can you print the array before inserting into the database add into the answer

Comment: @saurabhkamble see the image no. 1. like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an identifier on your employee attendance input name, so each employee have their own unique attendance dataset.

view :

```
    ...
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="detail[<?php echo $no-1 ?>][]" value="<?php echo $list['details']"></td>
    ...
```

Since the attendance input is a multidimensional array, for the `empty` validation, you could use `array_filter` to check the whole attendance array.

And because of you are inserting an array data type into a single column, you need to concatenate it, you could use `implode()` function.

controller :

```
function add_attend()
{
    $employee   = $this->input->post('employee');
    $location   = $this->input->post('location');
    $detail     = $this->input->post('detail');
    $note       = $this->input->post('note');
    $total      = count($employee);
    $filtered_detail = array_filter($detail);
    if (empty($filtered_detail) === true) {
        $errors['detail'] = 'please select one';
    }

    if (!empty($errors)){
        $info['success'] = false;
        $info['errors']  = $errors;
    }

    else {
        for ($x=0; $x<$total; $x++){
            $data = array(
                'sn'    => $employee[$x],
                'lab'   => $location[$x],
                'stat'  => (isset($detail[$x]) && !empty($detail[$x])) ? implode(",",$detail[$x]) : '',
                'note'  => $note[$x]
                );          
            $this->m_human_capital->insert_attend($data);
        }

        $info['success'] = true;
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($info));
}
```

Comment: like this <input type="hidden" name="employee[<?php echo $no-1 ?>][]" value="<?php echo $list_emp->sn; ?>">  ? i tried your code but i have error message.

Comment: NO.. it's just for `detail` input only

Comment: oh. ok. forgot my first comment.  i have tried like your code. but now the data not insert into database, i got error message undefined offset in line 'stat'. i will show you the error detail if im back to office.